# annotate_figure (ggpubr) failing with ggsave()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

When I use `annotate_figure()` from the `ggpubr` package, the preview that I get in the plots window of R looks great, but when I export the figure using `ggsave()`, the text that I've added is replaced by a black bar.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong, but it is happening on code that I previously ran without issue. Is anyone else having this issue? I'm running R version 4.1.2, ggplot2 version 3.3.5, and ggpubr 0.4.0. I'm new here - apologies if there  is information that you need but I haven't reported.

Here's a simple example with mtcars:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

car_example<-
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(text=element_text(size=12, family="serif", color="black"))

car_figure<-annotate_figure(car_example, left = text_grob("Example label", rot = 90, size=12, family="serif", color="black"))

ggsave(plot=car_figure, "car_example.jpeg", device = "jpeg", dpi=300, width = 3, height=3, units = "in")
```

This produces [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0mFi.png) in the preview window in R

But [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHgNQ.png) after I export with `ggsave` - the "Example label" text has been replaced with a black bar.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me on R 4.1.0, with the same ggplot and ggpubr versions as you. When you output to pdf do you get the same issue?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! That's bizarre - I don't have the same issue going to pdf. I've also tried .tiff which seems to work fine too. I don't know what's causing it, but this will work as a solution. Thanks!

Comment: @hdiza I'm also running all of the same versions as you, and it saves fine for me with the example label showing fine (at least on my MacBook Pro).

Comment: @hdiza so weird! Glad the workaround worked.

Comment: I got the same issue when running your code on my Mac and encountered similar issues in the past. One workaround (which worked for me) would be to set the background color when saving: `ggsave(..., bg = "white")`. See https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4212#issuecomment-701532730

Comment: This is great - thank you all for your input on this! Sorry that I previously missed the bug report.